# Can I borrow money from a player in Monopoly Deal game?

Tags: monopoly-deal

My bank has no money and I asked another player to give me from their bank with the condition that I will give repay it later on. Is that allowed?

Answer (score 5):

This is probably not allowed, but even if it was it would be unnecessary. From the [Rules Card](http://monopolydealrules.com/photos/instructions-front.png):

> If you have no cards in front of you to pay with, you don't pay at all!

So even if it were possible to borrow, why would you want to take on a debt when you could avoid paying by simply having no money in front of you?